# How to access data form Google sheets html sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, sidebar, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to access the values in my custom sidebar menu. Been trying to find the solution for too long.

My end goal is to create a new sheet in the active spreadsheet based on the response from the sidebar.

"ReferenceError: "document" is not defined."

```
     var assessmentName = document.getElementbyId.myForm.assessmentName
```

Below is the full program.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WQZxgz0jywmB3x-MQriBd7GLqpMpFu4XqR84tpHo8NQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  function onOpen() {
    var menu = [

    {name:"Add Marks", functionName:"addMarks"},
    ];
    ss.addMenu("MarkBook", menu);
  }
function addMarks(){
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html').setTitle('Add New Assessment');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);

         //test 0
            Logger.log(0)
            var assessmentName = document.getElementbyId.myForm.assessmentName
              Logger.log(assessmentName)
            var date = document.getElementbyId.date
              Logger.log(date)
            var assessment = document.getElementbyId.myForm.Assessment
              Logger.log(assessment)
            var input = document.myForm.input
              Logger.log(input)

    }


 //test 1 is in HTML file


function submitData() {

    Logger.log(2)//test start

              google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.myForm)

              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              Logger.log(myForm+2)

              var assessmentName =document.getElementById('assessmentName');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              Logger.log(assessmentName+2)

              var date =document.getElementById.date('date');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              Logger.log(date+2)

              var assessment =document.getElementById.myForm('Assessment');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              Logger.log(assessment+2)

              var input =document.getElementById.myForm.input('input');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              Logger.log(input+2)

      Logger.log("hi2")//test complete

 }



function onSuccess() {     


Logger.log(3)
   var assessmentName= document.getElementById('assessmentName').innerHTML = item;
    Logger.log(assessmentName+3)

   var date= document.getElementById.date('date').innerHTML = item;
    Logger.log(date+3)

   var assessment =document.getElementById.myForm('Name').innerHTML = item;
    Logger.log(assessment+3)

   var input= document.getElementById.myForm.input('input').innerHTML = item;
    Logger.log(input+3)


 Logger.log("hi3")

  }
```

HTML test in `<head>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <script>
                var assessmentName = document.getElementbyId.myForm.assessmentName
                Logger.log(assessmentName)
                var date = document.getElementbyId.date
                Logger.log(date)
                var assessment = document.getElementbyId.myForm.Assessment
                Logger.log(assessment)
                var input = document.myForm.input
                Logger.log(input)


     function submitData(){
          Logger.log(1)    

              var myForm =document.getElementById('myForm');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              logger.log(myForm+1)

              var assessmentName =document.getElementById('assessmentName');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              logger.log(assessmentName+1)

              var date =document.getElementById('date');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              logger.log(date)

              var assessment =document.getElementById('Assessment');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              log(assessment+1)

              var input =document.getElementById('input');
              google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(alert).submitform(form);
              log(input+1)


           Logger.log("hi1")


              }
             </script>
  </head>
```

Form to collect data to be used for edit google sheets.

```
 <body>

     <div>
        <form name="myFrom" id=myForm>

                Assessment Name:
                <br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Assessment Name" name="assessmentName">
                <br/>
                <br/>

                Date:
                <br/>
                <input type="date" id="date">
                <br/>
                <br/>

                Assessment Type:
                <br/>
                  Formative<input type="radio" name="Assessment" id="input" value="Formative"/>
                  Sumative<input type="radio" name="Assessment" id="input" value="Sumative"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                Input Method:
                <br/>
                <select name="input" id="input">
                  <option>Manually Input Data</option>
                  <option>Quiz Results Google Forms</option>
                  <option>Kahoot Spreadsheet</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                Sheet link:
                <br/>
                <input type="url" placeholder="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/****" name="id">
                <br/>
                <br/>

        </form>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()" />
        <button onclick="google.spript.run.submitData();" >Save</button>

         <input type="button" value="Close Sidebar" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
     </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The main task is to take <html>

            Assessment Name:
                <br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Assessment Name" name="assessmentName"> </html>

and return user input to  <script>
 var assessmentName =document.getElementById('assessmentName');</script>

Comment: I made a different spreadsheet with only the current issue. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UrhuyDmoaRhUbyq9Usm8FVaA6N3wvxW2A_uzAMeag44/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know how to edit my own question, but I could really use some support. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: A friend told me I need a database. So I just create a starting page to gather the info I wanted. It's not as functional as the sidebar could have been but I don't know databases yet.